# Make multi line design of tag control

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I have applied the evernote tag control which is working but the design is not in multi line as I add tag it is added next to the previous tag and adding in the single line, but it has to move down when there is no more space on the page. Here is the screenshot of what I want:
[image: what i want]
I have followed this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167809/how-can-i-create-a-tagging-control-similar-to-evernote-in-wpf but still unable to get the tags in multi line. Please let me know where I am going wrong. Following is my xaml:

```
<!-- EvernoteTagControl default style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:EvernoteTagControl}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="White" />
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="IconBrush" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="#5890f0" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#0351d7" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Style.Resources>       
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15 25 15 15" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:EvernoteTagControl}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />-->
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <!--<Path Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" Fill="{StaticResource IconBrush}" Height="19" Stretch="Uniform" Data="M 50.535714,0.44196425 0.00446427,34.754464 l 0,106.906246 100.71874573,0 0,-107.124996 L 50.535714,0.44196425 z m 0.1875,21.21874975 c 6.311826,0 11.40625,5.094424 11.40625,11.40625 0,6.311826 -5.094424,11.4375 -11.40625,11.4375 -6.311826,0 -11.4375,-5.125674 -11.4375,-11.4375 0,-6.311826 5.125674,-11.40625 11.4375,-11.40625 z" />-->
                    <ItemsPresenter Grid.Column="0" Margin="2"  />
                    <Button Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Click to add..." x:Name="PART_CreateTagButton">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <ContentPresenter TextElement.Foreground="#FF555555" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditing" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CreateTagButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- EvernoteTagItem default style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:EvernoteTagItem}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,2,0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,2,0,2" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:EvernoteTagItem}">
                <Button x:Name="PART_TagButton" Content="{TemplateBinding Text}" Foreground="#ffffff" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="#00698C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Background="#00698C" >
                                <Grid >
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,2" />
                                    <Button x:Name="PART_DeleteTagButton" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="3,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"   >
                                        <Button.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <Grid Height="10" Width="10" Background="#00698C" >
                                                    <Path Stretch="Uniform" ClipToBounds="True"  Stroke="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Data="M 85.364473,6.9977109 6.0640998,86.29808 6.5333398,85.76586 M 6.9926698,7.4977169 86.293043,86.79809 85.760823,86.32885"  />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Button.Template>
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <!--<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_DeleteTagButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>-->
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditing" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:EvernoteTagItem}">
                        <tkInput:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="PART_InputBox"
                                                         Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                         ItemsSource="{Binding AllTags, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:EvernoteTagControl}}}"
                                                         IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                                                         />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I am getting these tags as:
[image: I am getting this]

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Milney thanks for the link Now can you check and help me with the issue

Comment: @Amandeep I think the asp.net tag here is not needed, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you use a `StackPanel` as `ItemsPanel`, but a stack panel will never wrap its items in multiple dimensions. So instead, you should  try panels like `WrapPanel` or `UniformGrid`

For the `WrapPanel`, you also need to set a `Width` in the `ItemContainerStyle` in order to assure same size for all tag items (according to your *"what I want"* picture).

Then you have to decide on the positioning of your `PART_CreateTagButton` button. With multi lines of tags, the grid layout of `ItemsPresenter` and `PART_CreateTagButton` might no longer be appropriate.

You can probably create a compound items source of the original tag items source and the button as last item. This way, the button will always be properly aligned with the tags. See [Add extra items when using ItemsSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771679/add-extra-items-when-using-itemssource) and [How do you bind a CollectionContainer to a collection in a view model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446699/how-do-you-bind-a-collectioncontainer-to-a-collection-in-a-view-model) for more details.